# Is a pulled down signal the same as a ground signal?

Tags: multiplexer

I am using a multiplexer to switch my UART lines.  When the logic signal (A0/A1) is high the UART lines responsible for firmware downloads are connected to my MCU, when the signal is low a GNSS module sends serial data to the MCU.  In summary I am just switching what is connected to the TXD0 and RXD0 of my MCU.

I decided a good way to implement the signaling would be to use USB_VDD as my logic signal such that when I plug in my micro-usb the multiplexer would switch to logic high state (firmware download mode).  And unplugging it would take me to low logic mode (GNSS mode).

The problem is I am not sure if the logic signal my multiplexer sees when the USB is unplugged is adequate.  It is not a direct ground signal, just the VDD signal line is pulled down to ground by a 10k resistor.  Will this cause problems? [multiplexer datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmux1109.pdf?ts=1643056667643&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DTMUX1109RSVR)

[image: circuit]

[image: logic table]

Comment: it depends on the value of the pulldown resistor if there are internal pullups in the IC

Comment: Be careful what happens if USB_VDD is present but the 5V Continuous is not. As it happens the TMUX1109 is OK with that but others may not be.

Comment: @kevin they are asking about the resistor to ground in the first place.

Comment: @Passerby - Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking about. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes. A 10K resistor is a fairly standard pull up/down value. Not too strong not too weak. It should pull the line down enough when the rest of the node has no signal present. It's stronger than the stray signals or capacitance of the trance when nothing is connected.

As mentioned in the comments, if your input has any pull-up resistor, then it works like a voltage divider and the subsequent voltage will be a ratio of your external resistor and the internal one. But for these chips, it's unlikely they will have internal pull resistors. The datasheet makes no mention of it.

You can measure this with a multimeter to confirm.